# How can I slide up a Viewpager to show view?

Tags: android

I have a small layout, which is a viewpager at the bottom of the screen. I set it to be the handle of slidingdrawer. The problem is I can't drag viewpager to next page anymore if I do that. Please show me how to fix that.Thank you!

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/olp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />

    <SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:content="@+id/content"
        android:handle="@+id/handle" >


      <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
          android:id="@+id/handle"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#FFF000" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: post you code please

Comment: @andiyulistyo I don't think the problem is in the code - I just set function for viewpager and it worked before. I think the problem is when I set viewpager to the handle of slidedrawer, it become a button,  not a viewpager anymore, but I can't figure out how to fix that. Anyway, I update my layout, please take a look ;)